# После установки fedora слетел загрузчик win10

Tags: windows, grub, fedora, boot

Поставил Фёдору рядос с виндой и и после установки загружается только Федора, как то я это уже решал но не помню как, подскажите!

Comment: Вы в метке указали grub это и есть решение. Странно у меня в debian grub  сразу подхватил установленную рядом винду. C fedora не сталкивался, но думаю там что-то похожее c учетом что это также unix-подобная ос)

Comment: Загрузчик восстановил через консоль загрузочной флешки винды но теперь винда грузится а линукс пропал)